# How to bundle a dependency's resources along with my own aar?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building a library that uses another library which contains resources as a dependency. If it matters, that dependency is the Facebook SDK.

The problem is whenever I add my library as a dependency to another project it's not merging the dependency's resources to my aar.

Why this happens and why all the resources are not getting bundled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aar file doens't contain the transitive dependencies.

It means that you have to add these dependencies also in the project where you use the library.

An alternative is to publish the library in a maven repository (public or private). Gradle in this case with the pom file is able to download also the dependencies.

Comment: You mean that by default, aar files do not contain any transitive dependencies? If so, isn't there any way to include them?

Comment: I don't know a way to do it.I always use a maven repo.

Comment: Ok. But that behaviour (not including transitive dependencies) is particular for aar files and not to apks?

Comment: Is there any guide u can suggest to upload my library to maven repo? Sorry I have serached but couldn't find steps to do this.

Comment: Jcenter: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en, Central Maven: http://gmariotti.blogspot.it/2013/09/publish-aar-file-to-maven-central-with.html

Comment: @kaneda I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to find any other way apart from publishing to maven?