# Android library project depending on other library projects

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

For various reasons I am in a situation where I have multiple app components existing in small isolated android-library projects, which are being compiled out as `.aar`s.

In some cases these are pushed to a maven repo and consumed that way, which is fine and everything works great.

In other cases these aars need to be **compiled into another android library**. With my current config Im having issues as the child aar lib contents are not added to the parent aar lib project on `gradlew assembleRelease`.

Dependency flow is like

`Apk app project -> parentLibProject -*> childLibProject`

This results in the parent aar compiling fine as the child aars are on the classpath but **will not include the child aar libs contents in the output parent  aar**. This means any android application project which uses the parent lib will fail at compilation time as the child lib aar files/code are not in the parent aar. I do not want to go the route of forcing the app project to manually list all the child lib projects that have already been listed in the parent lib project. **In essence I want to aars to be treated in a similar way to `jar` libs that are used by a library project i.e. compiled into the output `aar`.**

I have tried a few non-successful approaches (which all ***build fine*** but all ***fail to output the child aar lib contents into the parent aar lib file***):

1. The compiled child `aar` inside `/libs/`, which is on declared in the repository closure with `flatDir { dirs 'libs' }` and imported to parent lib project with `compile(name:'someAarLib-x.y.z', ext:'aar')`. **This compiles fine but the parent project will also need to include the `someAarLib-x.y.z` aar and `compile(name:'someAarLib-x.y.z', ext:'aar')`.**
2. Importing the child aar as modules as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24894387/236743. This compiles fine but has the same problem as 1.
3. Using the same approach as https://stackoverflow.com/a/33264652/236743 but with `*.aar`. This does not work at all (as commented elsewhere on SO)

I am using Gradle 2.3 and android plugin 1.2.1 at present.

For now I am doing it in a hacky way of pulling the `classes.jar`s out of the child aar projects and putting the the parent lib project (as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/33264652/236743) as it just so happens that they dont use any xml resources so Im not losing anything in this case. But this is slightly time consuming and not very scalable / bit of manual work I dont want to do. Yes could automate this but im sure there is an offical way that I have just not stumbled across the correct config.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: It is not so clear what is the issue. Using aar files, you have to configure the maven to tell about flatdir, and you have to add a compile line in the dependency block.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that - have updated the question to be clearer about the issue. What you are suggesting sounds the same as no **1** above, which does not solve the problem.

Comment: The parent project aar will not contain the nested dependencies. It means that the parent aar will not contain the aar-child and the child dependencies. Check also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656906/how-to-bundle-a-dependencys-resources-along-with-my-own-aar/32658383#32658383

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know it will not by default (thats why I am asking) but am wondering if there is a way to make it so. It would be the same resolution/merge process as when an apk pulls in a aar files resources at build time so Im assuming I just have not hit upon the right config to make this happen (rather than it not being possible)

Comment: @Dori: Did you got any solution on this?

Comment: Nothing extra to add to the above no.